# Microsoft Image Moderation - Error when using own images

Tags: python, azure

I'm currently trying to use the Python API for Microsoft Moderator ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-contentmoderator/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.contentmoderator.operations.imagemoderationoperations?view=azure-python#evaluate-file-input-image-stream--cache-image-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false--callback-none----operation-config-)).
From the documentation, it is not clear how to send a request with your own images.
The input parameter is *image_stream*, but it is not clear to me how to load an image in such a format.

For example:

```
imf_path = "./img/img1.png"
img_stream = some_function()
evaluation = client.image_moderation.evaluate_file_input(
  media_type="image/png",
  cache_image=True,
  image_stream = image_stream
)
```

Where *client* is an initialized instance of *ContentModeratorClient*.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
imf_path = "<png path>"

evaluation = client.image_moderation.evaluate_file_input(
  media_type="image/png",
  cache_image=True,
  image_stream = open(imf_path , 'rb'),
)
```

Result:

[image]